# Could not create task ':app:processDevDebugMainManifest'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, gradle

when i run flutter project and getting this error on gradle build:
ould not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDevDebugManifest'.

> Could not create task ':app:processDevDebugMainManifest'.
> Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because "value" is null

what i have tried: i try so many solutions, nothing helps
intalled latest version, flutter clean, flutter pub get, flutter pub upgrade, reastart vscode,
restart windows, compare this project with other project that works fine, comparing AndroidManifest.xml files, comparing build.gradle 2 files and eliminating posibile dependencies that might cause this issue   -  N O T H I N G

finally with the help of CHATgpt i got the stacktrace, but still, i dont have access to gradle api files, and the classes inside them, so how can i do a debugg ?

sucks, i am stuck and instead of programming flutter - i deals with this issues.
for your convinience, i marked where the error begin, but again - i dont know how to debugg this.

any help will be highly aprreciated!

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because "value" is null
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.core.VariantDslInfoImpl$manifestPlaceholders$2.invoke(VariantDslInfoImpl.kt:854)**

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDevDebugManifest'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:68)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:49)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.getDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:147)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:121)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.discoverNodeRelationships(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:184)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.doAddEntryNodes(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:156)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:131)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:123)
  at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildTaskScheduler.scheduleRequestedTasks(TaskNameResolvingBuildTaskScheduler.java:53)
  at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildTaskScheduler.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultTasksBuildTaskScheduler.java:72)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:46)
  at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$DefaultBuildProjectRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:205)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$DefaultBuildProjectRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:198)
  at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:45)
  at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(VintageBuildModelController.java:76)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$1(StateTransitionController.java:110)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$2(StateTransitionController.java:125)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:121)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:109)
  at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.scheduleRequestedTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:76)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController$DefaultWorkGraphBuilder.addRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:255)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:38)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$3(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:143)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.java:42)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:120)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.run(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:91)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:68)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$4(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:143)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$1(StateTransitionController.java:110)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$2(StateTransitionController.java:125)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:121)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:109)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:143)
  at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:148)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildController.java:73)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraphBuilder.withWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:150)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$1(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:38)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraph$1.run(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraph.scheduleWork(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:192)        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$doScheduleAndRunTasks$3(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:96)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:109)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.doScheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:95)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$scheduleAndRunTasks$1(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:76)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$5(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:113)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$5(StateTransitionController.java:166)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:166)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
  at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:166)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:110)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:76)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:71)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:136)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
  at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
  at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
  at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
  at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
  at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:40)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
  at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
  at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':app:processDevDebugMainManifest'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.taskCreationException(DefaultTaskContainer.java:715)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.access$600(DefaultTaskContainer.java:76)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.domainObjectCreationException(DefaultTaskContainer.java:707)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:948)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.access$1401(DefaultTaskContainer.java:654)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider$1.run(DefaultTaskContainer.java:680)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultTaskContainer.java:676)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.calculateOwnValue(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:929)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:107)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.FlatMapProvider.backingProvider(FlatMapProvider.java:68)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.FlatMapProvider.getProducer(FlatMapProvider.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MappingProvider.getProducer(MappingProvider.java:58)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.getProducer(AbstractProperty.java:178)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.getProducer(AbstractProperty.java:178)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.getProducer(AbstractProperty.java:178)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.getProducer(AbstractProperty.java:178)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.ProviderBackedFileCollection.visitDependencies(ProviderBackedFileCollection.java:50)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:103)
  at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmptyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:213)
  at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)
  at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:66)
  ... 140 more
  **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because "value" is null
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.core.VariantDslInfoImpl$manifestPlaceholders$2.invoke(VariantDslInfoImpl.kt:854)**
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.core.VariantDslInfoImpl$manifestPlaceholders$2.invoke(VariantDslInfoImpl.kt:851)
  at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.core.VariantDslInfoImpl.getManifestPlaceholders(VariantDslInfoImpl.kt:851)
  at com.android.build.api.variant.impl.VariantImpl$manifestPlaceholders$2.invoke(VariantImpl.kt:121)
  at com.android.build.api.variant.impl.VariantImpl$manifestPlaceholders$2.invoke(VariantImpl.kt:116)
  at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
  at com.android.build.api.variant.impl.VariantImpl.getManifestPlaceholders(VariantImpl.kt:116)
  at com.android.build.api.variant.impl.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated.getManifestPlaceholders(Unknown Source)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest$CreationAction.configure(ProcessApplicationManifest.kt:421)
  at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessApplicationManifest$CreationAction.configure(ProcessApplicationManifest.kt:285)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.factory.TaskConfigurationActions.execute(TaskFactoryUtils.kt:94)
  at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.factory.TaskConfigurationActions.execute(TaskFactoryUtils.kt:80)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:44)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultMutationGuard$2.execute(DefaultMutationGuard.java:44)
  at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:110)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:107)
  at org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SetWithManyActions.execute(ImmutableActionSet.java:329)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:262)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.doAdd(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:113)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:256)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection$AbstractDomainObjectCreatingProvider.tryCreate(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:944)
  ... 166 more
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you are running by using flavor like "dev" when you start the Flutter project.

Comment: Could you be more specific about solution to this problem?